# What are the flower squares used for?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I recently started playing Clash of Clans on Android and I was wondering what those cornflower and other squares are used for?

Besides costly decoration it looks like they could be used for some type of obstacle to impede slow or down attackers or  even route them to a trap.

Anyone have some good ideas on how to use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beautification point aside, these decorations are not as useless as they seem to be ! (I don't like beautifying something that is meant to be attacked !). You can use these decorations as troop funnels ! The enemy troops cannot go through the flowers and go around them in small groups. So, with careful placement you can group up those archers by placing adjacent flowers so that the archers go between them and the mortar's damage takes care of the nuisance they cause ! Happy clashing ! Cheers !

Comment: A clarification of what I meant - If you place a line of these flowers west-east and make archers go north-south, they will get grouped together.

Comment: Hope you got the point ! Thnx for removing that comment ! Cheers !

Answer (score 2):

Some of these "Decoration" blocks (also referred to as squares)  can be used to disguise traps, or holes in your walls, or even as distractions. Other than that, there purely to make your base look "pretty".

Comment: I <3 pretty things. THEN I DESTROY THEM!!! BWAHAHA

Comment: Like any evil mastermind would >:) . Also if the answer helped you, don't forget to click that tick next to it , to select it as the best answer.